# teradata covalent td-menu-header

Tags: material-design, teradata-covalent

I had been looking thru all the documentation available at https://teradata.github.io/covalent/ but I didn't found any documentation about the "td-menu-header" found in the Teradata Covalent Quickstart.

This css framework seems interesting but the lack of documentation -it would be great a "API" documentation or developper guide- is putting us in a difficult choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used it this way. The code sample is present in Teradata Quickstart Project.

```
<button md-icon-button mdTooltip="Profile" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu"><md-icon class="md-24">person</md-icon></button>
    <md-menu #profileMenu="mdMenu">
        <td-menu>
            <div td-menu-header class="md-subhead">Profile</div>
            <div flex>
                <md-list dense>
                    <!--<h3 md-subheader>Metadata</h3>-->
                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>location_on</md-icon>
                        <h2 md-line *ngIf='client.address!==""'><span class="text-wrap">{{client.address}}</span></h2>
                        <h2 md-line *ngIf='client.address===""'>--</h2>
                        <p md-line>Address</p>
                    </md-list-item>
                    <md-divider md-inset></md-divider>
                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>location_city</md-icon>
                        <h2 md-line>{{client.city}}, {{client.state}}-{{client.zip}}</h2>
                        <p md-line>City,State-Zip</p>
                    </md-list-item>
                    <md-divider md-inset></md-divider>
                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>flag</md-icon>
                        <h2 md-line>{{client.country}}</h2>
                        <p md-line>Country</p>
                    </md-list-item>
                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>call</md-icon>
                        <h2 md-line>{{client.phone}}</h2>
                        <p md-line>Primary Phone</p>
                    </md-list-item>
                    <md-divider md-inset></md-divider>
                    <md-list-item *ngIf='client.phone2!==""'>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>call</md-icon>
                        <h2 md-line>{{client.phone2}}</h2>
                        <p md-line>Secondary Phone</p>
                    </md-list-item>
                    <md-divider md-inset *ngIf='client.phone2!==""'></md-divider>
                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>email</md-icon>
                        <h1 md-line><span class="text-wrap">{{client.email}}</span></h1>
                        <!--<h1 md-line></h1>-->
                        <p md-line>Primary Email {{client.email2}}
                        </p>
                    </md-list-item>
                    <md-divider md-inset></md-divider>
                    <md-list-item *ngIf='client.email2!==""'>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>email</md-icon>
                        <h1 md-line><span class="text-wrap">{{client.email2}}</span></h1>
                        <!--<h1 md-line></h1>-->
                        <p md-line>Secondary Email
                        </p>
                    </md-list-item>
                    <md-divider md-inset *ngIf='client.email2!==""'></md-divider>
                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon md-list-avatar>print</md-icon>
                        <h2 md-line *ngIf='client.fax!==""'>{{client.fax}}</h2>
                        <h2 md-line *ngIf='client.fax===""'>--</h2>
                        <p md-line>Fax</p>
                    </md-list-item>
                </md-list>
            </div>
        </td-menu>
    </md-menu>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur. I've noticed this tag in the Quick Start project at Github too.
But wouldn't It be nice to know all options and behavior of this tag?

Comment: And yes. It is possible to dig in the source code at Github to find them, but again, the actual docs at its web is incomplete and even not accurate. Just a remark.